# Half hour @ the Chanuka candles

Tags: halacha, chanuka

Is the half hour that you are supposed to make sure the candles are lit Shaa Zemanios or exactly thirty minutes?

Comment: The Shulchan Arukh just says 'about half an hour' so it probably doesn't matter. It's just an estimation of when the market would die down back then. (Basically irrelevant nowadays.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Kitzur Shulchan Aruch (139:10) gives the rule about half an hour without any further specification, and then further (in the same paragraph) states that the earliest one may light is at plag haminchah, which he defines in terms of shaos zemanios. This would seem to indicate that, at least according to him, this half hour means just that - exactly 30 minutes.